# Convert Excel Sheet to Web Page + Horizonal Scrolling

Tags: website-design, web-app, web, ux-designer

I have a Excel Sheet that I am trying to translate over to web page. The issue I am running into is that if I have a lot of columns that causes horizontal scrolling.

I could also have 100+ rows that display information

For example (not the actual data, thanks to http://www.mockaroo.com):
[image: Example]

Any Recommendation on how to make UI/UX experience for users easier so it shows them all the information and they can update the data in one page?

Comment: I hope you didn't put actual users' info as an example...

Comment: its mock data... https://www.mockaroo.com/

Comment: Good to hear that. And thank you for the tip on mock data.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the information you need to show about the users can be grouped as following:

- first and last name (these columns can be concatenated)
- email address
- gender - can be shown as a pictogram ♂ or ♀ (or any other understood by the target group)
- IP addresses (11 entries per user) - can be shown as (editable) drop down, where control decoration appears on hover.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmGoqp.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Or you can have a fixed-width text box accommodating e.g 2½ of an IP address with `...` (indicating there is more) that expands on click allowing the user to edit the data.

If there are other data types, try grouping them like I described with IP addresses

Comment: one thing I would need to show is the ipaddress 1- 11 as label. so users know which one they are updating.

Comment: I've added a mockup - a dialog that appears on clicking on the (truncated) IP addresses list. In fact, each IP should reside in a separate frame.